# How to get React preventDefault to work 'e.preventDefault();' not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I've got an issue with my react application whereby I want to prevent default behaviour when submitting a form. However, when I submit my form, the preventDefault() doesn't seem to do anything. Also, when hovering over the e perimeter in my function, and the preventDefault method, vscode doesn't give any information on it, signalling that it doesn't seem to be recognising it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Feed.css';
import CreateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Create';
import ImageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Image';
import SubscriptionsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Subscriptions';
import EventNoteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EventNote';
import CalendarViewDayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CalendarViewDay';
import InputOption from './InputOption';
import Post from './Post';

function Feed() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    const sendPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <div className="feed">
            <div className="feed__inputContainer">
                <div className="feed__input">
                    <CreateIcon />
                    <form>
                        <input type="text"></input>
                        <button onClick={sendPost} type="submit">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="feed__inputOptions">
                    <InputOption Icon={ImageIcon} title="Photo" color="#70B5F9" />
                    <InputOption Icon={SubscriptionsIcon} title="Video" color="#E7A33E" />
                    <InputOption Icon={EventNoteIcon} title="Event" color="#C0CBCD" />
                    <InputOption Icon={CalendarViewDayIcon} title="Write Article" color="#7FC15E" />
                </div>
            </div>
            {posts.map((post) => (
                <Post />
            ))}
            <Post name="James Osborne" description="This is a test" message="This is a message" />

        </div>
    );
}

export default Feed
```

Comment: May be this helps https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010

Comment: try adding `e.stopPropagation()` after preventDefault line; as well. see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to apply on submit in form tag not with button click like that

```
  <form onSubmit={sendPost} >
      <input type="text"></input>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Abdullah said you should use a submit event to be able to prevent the default behavior, and also make the form work when the user pressed the enter key.

VSCode has no idea about the exact type of `e` so it assumes `e` has a type of `any`, so it can't determine whether a method named `preventDefault` exists and what type it has.

You can give hints to the editor using JSDoc comments:

```js
/**
 * @param {Event} e
*/
const sendPost = (e) => {
    // now it gives you some suggestions when typing 'e.'
}
```